# Setting mysql server name with and without www

Tags: mysql

I am using a mysql server on my linux ubuntu 10.04.
Everything is working fine, when I use `example.com` as the mysql server name.

When I use `www.example.com` as the mysql server name, the connection does not work. Where can I change the settings.
The URL of my website is working with www and without.

Is the mysql server name a setting in the mysql configuration or is it the hostname of my domain?

Comment: Your website is being written in which language? If your database and website code reside on same server then you can also use "localhost"

Comment: html / php. Why does it matter?

Comment: It does. without knowing your programming language how can someone suggest why connection didnt work and whats the remedy

Comment: Do `host example.com` and `host www.example.com` return the same IP?

Comment: @user1939706 You should definitely connect to the database using `localhost` and only allow localhost connections in MySQL. Using the global host name/ip will possibly let anyone connect to the database.

Comment: The thing is: Connection to my website and from my website with php code works well, as long as I take as the mysql server address the example.com without the www. Usually I could live with that. But I use an iPad app to connect to my mysql database. There is no possibility to add there a server address without the www. So it alwasy tries to connect with www.example.com as the mysq server address and fails.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Only if you create accounts for those remote clients.

Comment: To answer your question, the server name just uses DNS lookup to get the IP, it's not a setting in the server.

Comment: Hi Joachim. I was so blind. Of course... when I connect through ssh with my server I can connect as localhost.... of course! Thanks a lot. Now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check your MySQL servers users table. When you see the user, edit it and set this value for the host he/she can connect to:

%example.com

The % is a wildcard for everything in front of "example.com". The second alternative is to add a new user<->host combination via CREATE USER http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-user.html

**BUT ATTENTION**: You should never, never, never connect to your MySQL from outside localhost. And if so, use an SSH Tunnel to do so.